# uninitialized constant errror in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

Hi keep getting this error in rails when I try to create a new product in my e-commerce shop, the error is as follows: NameError in "ProductsController#update uninitialized constant Product::Categories". I am basically trying to assign a category to a product so for example a product named White polo would go in  the categories Tops etc… It shows a drop down list with all the categories when I am creating the product but when I click on create I get the exception.

The code for my controller is as follows:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :authorize, only: [:show]        

# GET /products
# GET /products.json
def index
@products = Product.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @products }
end
end

# GET /products/1
# GET /products/1.json
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@cart = current_cart

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end
end

def preview
@product = Product.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # preview.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end
end  


# GET /products/new
# GET /products/new.json
def new
@product = Product.new
@categories = Category.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end
end

# GET /products/1/edit
def edit
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@categories = Category.all
end

# POST /products
# POST /products.json
def create
@product = Product.new(params[:product])


respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to products_url, 
      notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, 
      location: @product }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, 
      status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    format.html { redirect_to @product, 
      notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, 
      status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to products_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
  end


  def who bought 
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
  format.atom
    end
end
 end
```

Product edit view code:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

 <ul>
 <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
 <li><%= msg %></li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.collection_select :categories, Category.all, :category_id, :category_name, :include_blank =>'None' %><br />
 </div> 

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_area :description, rows: 6 %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :image_url %><br />
<%= f.text_field :image_url %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :image_url1 %><br />
<%= f.text_field :image_url1 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :image_url2 %><br />
<%= f.text_field :image_url2 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :image_url3 %><br />
<%= f.text_field :image_url3 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :price %><br />
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :quantity %><br />
<%= f.text_field :quantity %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you hadn't declared the associations between Product and Category in their respective models (in Product, add `belongs_to :category`, and in Category, add  `has_many :products`).  You would also need to be sure that the products database table has a column `category_id`.

Comment: I changed the associations in the model and it now gives me this[code] ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ProductsController#create

Category(#70130619569040) expected, got String(#70130579263940)[code]

Comment: A good way to get a handle on these kinds of problems is to run `rails console`.  From the prompt, find a Product, e.g. `p = Product.find :first` then see, does it have a category? `c = p.category` -- that should return a Category object (check with `c.class`).  To assign a category, find a valid id (`new_c = Category.find :first` then `p.category = new_c.id`, then `p.save!`  If you can do all of this in the console, then you have narrowed down where the problem lies.

Comment: I just tried the console and i got the following 1.9.2p290 :002 > c = p.category
 => nil 
1.9.2p290 :003 > c.class
 => NilClass 
and then I tried the last command and got the same error as before.

Comment: So, this tells me that Product *does* know about category (otherwise `p.category` would have raise a NoMethodError exception).  I might have had an error in my prior response.  So, instead, find a valid category (`c = category.find :first`) and try `p.category = c` and then `p.save!`

Comment: It shows category Id as nil could this be the problem?             1.9.2p290 :012 > p.save
=> #<Category id: 1, created_at: "2012-03-21 14:25:26", updated_at: "2012-03-21 14:35:42", category_name: "T-shirt", category_id: nil> 
1.9.2p290 :012 > p.save

Comment: `p` should be an instance of Product, but it appears, from the output of `p.save => #<Category ...` that it is an instance of Category, and further that the associations are set up incorrectly.  Product should `belong_to :category', and Category should `have_many :products`, and the products table should have a column `category_id` (it's foreign key).  I suggest you take a careful look at this excellent guide to be sure you understand: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it now, what happened is I created a category_id column when their was no need to as rails had already created one called id so when I tried to create a new product it would have a mismatch and give me back those exceptions. Using the rails console was really useful as I dug deep and found out what was actually in the categories table.